# split json object from json array in java

Tags: java, arrays, json, http

I am sending API call to a service that return a json array like this :

```
[Object, Object ....]
```

via my java `http` request. the resulat are stored in a string:

```
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
```

I need to find a way to `split` this string to by json objects so each new string will contain only one object.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a sample of how the string look like? To split string there are quite a few methods using regex and non-regex solutions

Comment: the string looks like a jsonArray.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using the `split` function, you can convert your String to a `JSONArray` and then iterate throw the array

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.toString());
for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String jsonObjectAsString = jsonObject.toString();
}
```