# Split string contining two jsons into two jsons in Java

Tags: java, json, string

I have problem with getting two jsons from String:
`{"doc":{"sheet":{"english":{"link":"http://localhost?id=123&format=pdf"}}}}{"doc":{"term":{"english":{"link":"http://localhost?id=12&format=pdf"}}}}`

I tried to use simple-json but it can't deal with two jsons and says that `{{{{` are illegal. I was also thinking about splitting it (but by what) somehow into two strings and then create json. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Try to use JSONArray for this, here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33754239/10802597

Comment: How does this happen in the first place? Can't you fix the origin of this instead of working around it?

Comment: @luk2302
nope, it comes to me like this, can't change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `"}{"` does not appear in any field value itself you can split at exactly `"}{"` since that is not valid within the json structure. Alternatively find the index of that string, add one and split on that index.

Comment: Not exactly.  You mean split on `(?<=})(?={)` ... this will retain the brackets used for splitting.

Comment: This will only work if both values are objects. What if one of them is an array or primitive value?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, but in that case I would prefer appending the removed brackets manually or using the split on the index instead.

Comment: @Henry not sure if this can happen but you can construct something similar to `}{` for those cases as well, just gets a little more complex. Depends on what OP really needs.